# how to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in production?

Tags: django

There is next line in manage.py file:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings.development")
```

So by default it will use **my_project.settings.development** settings. But in production i need "my_project.settings.production" settings, 
so i did

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="my_project.settings.development"
```

But it works only while i don't exit from session.

How to set this variable for long time?

ps: I can't add this to my virtual env activate file, because 
i use next line for cron task:

`*` `*` `*` `*` `*` `/home/.virtualenvs/my_project/bin/python /home/my_project/src/manage.py task`

Answer (score 0):

In each environment you can add the export to your `~/.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.development
```

And in `wsgi.py`, `manage.py` leave it as:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
```

Also it will be easy to manage if you use some sort of provisioning so that the appropriate one will be set automatically in all dev/staging/prod machines when recreated.